# explicit many to many self-relations produces weird results in the generated client, pairing up wrong values

Tags: prisma

I've got `users` and `contact requests` with a table in between to explicitly define a self relation for cascade purposes.

user schema:

```
  contactRequestsReceivedFrom ContactRequestRelations[] @relation("contactRequestReceivedFrom")
  contactRequestsMadeTo       ContactRequestRelations[] @relation("contactRequestMadeTo")
```

relations schema:

```
model ContactRequestRelations {
  contactRequestReceivedFrom User   @relation("contactRequestReceivedFrom", fields: [requestReceivedFromId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  contactRequestMadeTo       User   @relation("contactRequestMadeTo", fields: [requestMadeToId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  requestReceivedFromId      String
  requestMadeToId            String

  @@id([requestReceivedFromId, requestMadeToId])
}
```

• I have to give the relations a name, prisma will complain it's too ambiguous otherwise
• if I give the same relation reference on all 4 of them, prisma will complain of "wrongly named relation detected"

I wanted to make a 'send contact request' operation.

Where I find either the user that the request is made for and then add the relation to the 'contactRequestsReceivedFrom`array ---- or ---- find the user that is sending the request and create a relation on the`contactRequestsMadeTo`.

The issue is, even though the relation   `contactRequestsReceivedFrom ContactRequestRelations[] @relation("contactRequestReceivedFrom")` on the user is clearly paired with the `contactRequestReceivedFrom User   @relation("contactRequestReceivedFrom", fields: [requestReceivedFromId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)` relation on the relation table, when I attempt to create this with the client, prisma only lets me define the opposite of that relation which is rather redundant and confusing:

[image]

as it would serve no purpose to define in that context, as I would be defining who made the request.

Is this the correct pattern/syntax, or should I be looking at a more complex model with a couple more tables in between? Not a big fan of that option.

Comment: Do you mind adding the entire User model? I would like to run this locally to try and find a solution.

Comment: @NurulSundarani Don't think that's necessary anymore, I think my approach of creating the relations & everything was a bit wrong, instead of going user -> create relation, I've now adjusted my queries to just go directly to the relation table and create a new row there, this has generated a lot more consistent and predictable results that I was able to fully understand. 

Do you know if there are any downsides in doing things this way?

Comment: No, there are no downsides, you can definitely create a new record in the relation table.